# Android: Improve UI performance

Tags: android, performance

I have an app which shows a Dashboard fragment on startup. I've only designed the UI (XML) so far and i've noticed that on startup my app takes around 1.5 seconds to open while other apps on my phone are taking less than 0.5 seconds. I think that the graphic rendering is taking too much memory or maybe i've designed it in a wrong way.

My UI code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--
        Main Content
    -->
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--
            The Upper layer
        -->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/upper_layer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingBottom="100dp"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@drawable/img_user_colored_1"
                    android:id="@+id/imageView" app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/img_user_colored_1"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

            <TextView
                    android:text="Welcome, Mervin"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView2" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
                    tools:text="Title" app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
                    style="@style/typography_h6"/>

            <TextView
                    android:text="@string/TextView_fromDashboardFragment_Title_Main"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    tools:text="@string/TextView_fromDashboardFragment_Title_Main"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
                    style="@style/typography_caption"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <!--
            The lower content.
        -->

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/lower_layer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingBottom="16dp">

            <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    layout="@layout/include_forfragmentdashboard_section_goal"/>

            <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    layout="@layout/include_forfragmentdashboard_section_todo"/>

            <include
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    layout="@layout/include_forfragmentdashboard_section_tobuy"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <!--
        The anchored CardView on the middle of the screen
    -->

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/active_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardView_background_default"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/Elevation_CardView_Simple"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/upper_layer"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/Padding_CardView_Simple"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/Padding_CardView_Simple"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Active"
                    style="@style/typography_overline"/>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="14"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            style="@style/typography_h2"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="@string/App_Lifestyle_Task_Goal_Title"
                            style="@style/typography_caption"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            style="@style/typography_h2"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="@string/App_Lifestyle_Task_ToDo_Title"
                            style="@style/typography_caption"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:baselineAligned="false">

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="24"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                            style="@style/typography_h2"/>

                    <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:text="@string/App_Lifestyle_Task_ToBuy_Title"
                            style="@style/typography_caption"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

include_forfragmentdashboard_section_tobuy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/App_Lifestyle_Task_ToBuy_Title"
        style="@style/Centered_Subtitle_Overline_Default"/>

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardView_background_default"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/Elevation_CardView_Simple">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Margin_CardView_Simple"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    style="@style/typography_h2"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="All Time"
                    style="@style/typography_caption"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardView_background_default"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/Elevation_CardView_Simple">

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/Margin_CardView_Simple"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:baselineAligned="false">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="56"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    style="@style/typography_h2"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="Completed"
                    style="@style/typography_caption"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</LinearLayout>


<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Priorities"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextAlternateLight"
        style="@style/typography_caption"/>


<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="2">

    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:max="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_MaxProgress"
            android:progress="56"
            android:progressTint="@color/item_priority_1"
            android:scaleY="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_ScaleY"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:max="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_MaxProgress"
            android:progress="56"
            android:progressTint="@color/item_priority_2"
            android:scaleY="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_ScaleY"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="2">

    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:max="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_MaxProgress"
            android:progress="56"
            android:progressTint="@color/item_priority_3"
            android:scaleY="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_ScaleY"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>

    <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:max="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_MaxProgress"
            android:progress="56"
            android:progressTint="@color/item_priority_4"
            android:scaleY="@integer/ProgressBar_Default_ScaleY"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The output is:

[image: UI-1]

[image: UI-2]

Can someone help me in improving the UI with some codes or some best UI practices that i can follow to fully optimize my UI? Are there some codes that you can enter in the xml or code behind to reduce overdraws? 
Please help me.

Comment: You have done lots and lots of nesting . Try to do this with constraint layout . As constraint layout is for complex view only . nested weights are bad for performance.

Comment: It looks like you could use a RecyclerView there. Also, too many nested LinearLayouts.

Comment: Does using constraint layout gives better performance that the other layouts ?

Comment: Definitely , It is used for complex layouts in order  to get rid of nested layouts . https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html

Comment: Thank you so much ! I will try to use constraint layout as far as possible. Any other best practices or code to optimize UI ?